# How to Skip or Eliminate Last Left Join in Query

Tags: sql-server

I have optional parametered stored procedure, But the query is working fine and has proper indexing on table. But when the last parameter is passed i:e Department Code and others can be as NULL. The query is taking long while and not producing the resulting. The time keeps incrementing but result is never retrieved.

Any suggestions on how to Skip unused join which is not related in this scenario.

In this scenario I can skip the below join.

```
LEFT  JOIN EMPLOYEEADDRESS EA ON EA.EmployeeDetailsFK = ED.Id
```

Any Suggestions how can I avoid this join to make the query execution faster.

Please find the complete query below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prGetStudentData
(
@FirstName VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@EmployeeCode VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@Address VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@DepartmentCode VARCHAR(50) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT E.* FROM EMPLOYEE E
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEEDETAILS ED ON ED.EmployeeFK = E.Id
LEFT  JOIN EMPLOYEEADDRESS EA ON EA.EmployeeDetailsFK = ED.Id
LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT D ON D.Id = ED.DepartmentFK
WHERE (@FirstName IS NULL OR (E.FirstName = @FirstName) AND
 (@EmployeeCode IS NULL OR (ED.EmployeeCode = @EmployeeCode) AND
 (@Address IS NULL OR (EA.Address = @Address) AND
 (@DepartmentCode IS NULL OR (D.DepartmentCode = @DepartmentCode)
END
```

Comment: You say this is the complete query, but none of the parameters are used at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT E.* FROM EMPLOYEE E
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEEDETAILS ED ON ED.EmployeeFK = E.Id
LEFT  JOIN EMPLOYEEADDRESS EA ON EA.EmployeeDetailsFK = ED.Id
LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT D ON @DepartmentCode IS NOT NULL AND D.Id = ED.DepartmentFK
WHERE (@FirstName IS NULL OR (E.FirstName = @FirstName)) AND
 (@EmployeeCode IS NULL OR (ED.EmployeeCode = @EmployeeCode)) AND
 (@Address IS NULL OR (EA.Address = @Address)) AND
 (@DepartmentCode IS NULL OR (D.DepartmentCode = @DepartmentCode))
```

or

```
SELECT E.* FROM EMPLOYEE E
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEEDETAILS ED ON ED.EmployeeFK = E.Id
LEFT  JOIN EMPLOYEEADDRESS EA ON EA.EmployeeDetailsFK = ED.Id    
WHERE (@FirstName IS NULL OR (E.FirstName = @FirstName) AND
 (@EmployeeCode IS NULL OR (ED.EmployeeCode = @EmployeeCode) AND
 (@Address IS NULL OR (EA.Address = @Address) AND
 (@DepartmentCode IS NULL OR 
        EXISTS(SELECT * 
               FROM DEPARTMENT D 
               WHERE D.Id = ED.DepartmentFK 
               AND D.DepartmentCode = @DepartmentCode)
 )
```

Comment: I have tried the first query on before hand does not work. I have tried to play around with this line LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT D ON @DepartmentCode IS NOT NULL AND D.Id = ED.DepartmentFK. But doesnt works

Comment: @user1030181 and second query ?

Comment: Works Functionally. but is there any way that I can eliminate duplicates from Employee Table without using DISTINCT, because DISTINCT is very slow performance. For Second Query

Comment: Did you try it with `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: Yups Still Slow in Execution on plan

Comment: Any Alternative Way for this to query up

Comment: I think duplicates are from `INNER JOIN` on EMPLOYEEDETAILS, try to write `EXISTS` for this table too and remove this inner join.

Answer (score 1):

An easy answer is to choose a select conditionally.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prGetStudentData (
       @FirstName VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
       @EmployeeCode VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
       @Address VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
       @DepartmentCode VARCHAR(50) = NULL
     ) AS BEGIN

 IF @DepartmentCode IS NULL
   SELECT E.* 
     FROM            EMPLOYEE E
          INNER JOIN EMPLOYEEDETAILS ED ON ED.EmployeeFK = E.Id
          LEFT  JOIN EMPLOYEEADDRESS EA ON EA.EmployeeDetailsFK = ED.Id
          LEFT  JOIN DEPARTMENT D ON D.Id = ED.DepartmentFK
    WHERE (@FirstName IS NULL OR (E.FirstName = @FirstName) 
      AND (@EmployeeCode IS NULL OR (ED.EmployeeCode = @EmployeeCode) 
      AND (@Address IS NULL OR (EA.Address = @Address) 
      AND (@DepartmentCode IS NULL OR (D.DepartmentCode = @DepartmentCode)
 ELSE
   SELECT E.* 
     FROM            EMPLOYEE E
          INNER JOIN EMPLOYEEDETAILS ED ON ED.EmployeeFK = E.Id
          LEFT  JOIN EMPLOYEEADDRESS EA ON EA.EmployeeDetailsFK = ED.Id
    WHERE (@FirstName IS NULL OR (E.FirstName = @FirstName) 
      AND (@EmployeeCode IS NULL OR (ED.EmployeeCode = @EmployeeCode) 
      AND (@Address IS NULL OR (EA.Address = @Address) 

 END
```

Comment: I have tried this out but bit worry with execution plan....is there any other better performance way to optimize the query. How about using CASE with SELECT?

Comment: `IF @DepartmentCode VARCHAR(50) IS NULL` should be `IF @DepartmentCode IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Stored procs that have multiple optional input parameters can be problematic.  Stored procs that perform search functionality are good examples.

One of the more common ways for such a query to be written in SQL is with multiple predicates in the where clause of the form `(WHERE SomeColumn = @SomeVariable OR @SomeVariable IS NULL)`.  While this works, the problem is that it works fairly inefficiently.  On large tables, it can result in really poor query performance.

Often, a better option is to use parameterized dynamic sql via `sp_executesql`.  Check out [Gail Shaw's Catch-All Queries](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) blog post.